# Javascript settimeout timer stopped while laptop lid is closed

Tags: javascript, settimeout

When my system goes to hibernate mode, the javascript timer stop the countdown and when it comes back it continue with the countdown.

But my problem is that I'd like the countdown to continue when my system goes to hibernate mode. Is there any solution / workaround to achieve that?

Comment: Don't close the lid then.

Comment: if not closing the lid its working fine. but client used to close the lid

Comment: You can't. `setTimeout` working during hibernation mode would require the browser to be running, which it can't do in hibernation. (Obviously)

Comment: Then you are out of options. You can't run a program on a computer that's effectively not working.

Comment: Don't use your laptop as a server then... Running client-side languages will stop running when the browser isn't running.

Comment: This is quite possibly the funniest Q&A I have ever seen on StackOverflow... "Why won't my program run when my computer is effectively switched off?"

Comment: thanks for ur reply #Tobsta

Comment: i'm not using laptop as server. the timer run in client side machine only it need to run while system goes hibernate also that y.... #NewToJS

Comment: Hibernation mode saves the state of your machine to the hard drive then shuts down entirely. Zero power. Zero processing.

Comment: @Karthik Read the answer below posted by **Jon Story** That explains why your javascript won't continue to run while the computer is in hibernate. Also first comments tells you why it won't continue to run. Hibernate + browser = no functionality because the computer isn't processing information any more, hence `hibernate`. No processing = no browser processes - timer or javascript.

Answer (score 4):

This isn't really a javascript issue.

When you close the lid,  your laptop is hibernating, meaning the CPU is switched off and cannot calculate things.

You have three options

1) Make the laptop stay on when closing the lid, or don't close the lid

2) Stop doing timer tasks client side, and instead simply start a timer on the server. Depending on what you are trying to achieve, this may or may not be relevant, but it is the only way to know the user will keep their lid open/browser open/machine on etc.

3) Re-work your code so instead of using a timer that says "wait ten seconds", you instead set it to use absolute times, something like the following (which is vague pseudo-code to demonstrate what I mean, not a working solution)

```
var targetTime;
var running = false;

startTimer(timeInSeconds)
{
    targetTime = now() + timeInSeconds;
    running = true;
}

while(running)
{
    if(now() > targetTime)
    {
        doTimerThings();
        running = false;  
    }
}
```

This will not get the timer precisely right, but will fire as soon as possible after the machine is started again. You can change your logic to suit how you wish to handle this (eg handling things differently if the timer is being fired late)

It won't help if you need to fire the timer at exactly the interval... but that simply isn't possible when the computer is off.

Comment: ok... thanks for ur solution... will try to keep timer in server side instead of using in client side

Comment: Option 3 would be best in my opinion, assuming there are no security concerns with doing it clientside

Comment: Whether you use #2 or #3 will depend on the task - if you simply want to show a "Done" message 1 minute after starting a "Please wait 1 minute" timer, #3 will work great. If you need to perform an update every 1 minute for the next 10, #2 is a better option